# How to install anything from github

Tags: android, github

I am trying to install this from github into my android aplication, but I don't know how I have to do it.

I am trying install this:

https://github.com/Maxwin-z/XListView-Android

thanks

EDIT=========================

MainActivity.java

```
import me.maxwin.view.XListView;
import me.maxwin.view.XListView.IXListViewListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IXListViewListener {
XListView lv1;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private String[] sistemas = {"Ubuntu", "Android", "iOS", "Windows", "Mac OSX", 
        "Google Chrome OS", "Debian", "Mandriva", "Solaris", "Unix"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv1=(XListView)findViewById(R.id.xListView);
    lv1.setPullLoadEnable(true);
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sistemas);
    lv1.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onLoadMore() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

Xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<me.maxwin.view.XListView 
    android:id="@+id/xListView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"> 
    </me.maxwin.view.XListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you want that to have as standalone application? Just download and play around with that? Or you want it to have as a part of your already existing app?

Comment: I want use that listview in my android projet that I am designing

Answer (score 0):

download it and add it to your workspace then refer to it as a library or just an ordinary project depends on your needs

EDIT:

refer to this for creating a library
[Creating Android Library Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135842/creating-android-library-project)

Comment: then how do I refer it as a library for use it in my android proyect?

Comment: well, I have used that tutorial correctly, but where is the listview now?

Comment: u can import it and use it in your project. its the same as using the standard ListView class.

Comment: I have added the library in my project, then all listview that I use in that project will is a Xlistview?

Comment: if you import me.maxwin.XListView and use XListView for your listview variable,yes.

Comment: listvi may not be a widget of XListView make sure in your xml you use the Xlistview widget.

`<me.maxwin.view.XListView
        android:id="@+id/xListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
    </me.maxwin.view.XListView>`

Comment: if it looks for XLIstViewClass, look into this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829959/customized-gui-components-for-android-in-eclipse on how to use Custom Widgets

Comment: there is an error yet

11-27 08:27:41.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1174): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 08:27:41.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1174): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pruebaxlist/com.example.pruebaxlist.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.pruebaxlist.MainActivity

Comment: did you add your MainActivity to the manifest file? if not , add it.

Comment: I have changed my virtual device to api18,and it launch this error
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1283): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pruebaxlist/com.example.pruebaxlist.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.pruebaxlist.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.pruebaxlist-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.pruebaxlist-1, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(1283): atdalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)